# Best strategy to use Git to maintain multiple similar projects?

Tags: git, git-fork

I have a completed project - we'll call it Foo. It's hosted on my own Gogs server.

Now, I have a request to create a derivative of the project, we'll call it Bar. The Foo and Bar projects will share a large portion of their codebase.

However, both the Foo and the Bar projects will have assets that must be different for each project. (Things like images, CSS files, etc.)

I am aware that I can make a copy of my Foo repo and create a Bar repository on my Gogs server, and then add the Foo repo as a second remote to the Bar project. However, what I'm not clear on is the best strategy to keep certain files separate while allowing changes to other files to be shared.

Example: If I make a fix to "backend.js", I want to be able to apply that change to both repositories. However, if I change "assets/logo.jpg", I want that change to only apply to the repo that the change is made in.

So let's say I do two commits on Bar: one changing the logo and one fixing a bug in backend.js. Other than cherry-picking files and moving them back and forth by hand, is there a better way to set this up so that changes to the backend.js file will be pushed to the Foo origin, but the changes to the logo will *not* be pushed?

Comment: use your language's package manager and split out reusable components into packages and consume them in both?

Comment: while i cannot offer a good answer to your question, you might want to have a look at "git submodules" and "git  subtree"

Comment: In my experience, branches are for features. Repositories are for projects. And projects can include, common shared libaries via package manager (private npm registry) or if you insist on git, use git submodules. (Or even copy pasted boilerplate.) The idea of having a whitelabel project seems enticing, and that you "only need some couple of changes" to kick a new project out of the door. That rarely, if never, will work out. There's no best strategy here.

Comment: Which approach did you end up taking? I'm thinking of keeping the repos private and forking from the main repo. That side any project side changes can be done on the main master repo, then pulled down to the forked projects?

Answer (score 0):

Even though very not optimal, you can achieve what you want by separating the files between branches:

1. Foo branch - contains unique files for Foo
2. Bar branch - contains unique files for Bar
3. Shared branch - contains common files

Obviously, the shared branch can be removed, if you decide that the Foo (or Bar) branch will also contain the shared files.

This way, you'll be able to push specific files to a specific remote:

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

After pushing the files, you'll have to merge the branch to an integration branch, if you want to see all files together at the same folder.
So, for your example:

- Fix backend.js in Shared branch, and push to Foo and Bar
- Merge Shared branch to integration branch
- Fix logo.jpg in Bar branch, and push only to Bar
- Merge Bar branch to integration branch

But, I think this is an annoying workflow, which is prone to errors.

From my experience, the best solution is to change the concept and use multiple repositories:

1. Bar.git - contains unique files for Bar
2. Foo.git - contains unique files for Foo
3. Shared.git - contains common files (can be removed, if you decide common files are part of Foo.git or Bar.git)

It's easier than branches since the files are separated completely, all files are exposed together, and you won't have to do merges or remember to which remote you need to push.

The question is how to manage the integration between the multiple GITs, and how to share the changes with other users. I would recommend using a tool for multiple repositories.

GIT has submodules feature which allows you "instantiate" other GIT repositories inside a main GIT repository:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Or GIT subtree:

https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree

But, above all, I think using Google REPO is the best **open source** option:

https://source.android.com/source/using-repo

This is a tool developed by Google to manage multiple GIT repositories for the Android project. In general, you define in a XML file which GIT repositories you are using, and for each GIT you can specify the branch you are working on, or commit number you are using.

So, the tool clones for you all the GITs automatically, and checkout the commit number that is specified in the XML. You commit and push in the GITs as usual. When you want to update other users with your changes, you update the XML.

Comment: The problem I have with submodules is that they require the "static" or "shared" code to be a subdirectory off the "unique" code. This doesn't work for my project as the root of the project is the shared code, and the unique parts are a subdirectory. I can't restructure the project further due to the CI used by my client (I have to add their Git server as another remote to the project and push code when ready for deployment, and they just run a gulpfile in the project root, so the shared code *must* be the project root).